# Please help me with this calculus question

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

The coefficients of the quadratic function $f(x)$ including the constant term, are all
rational and $f(x)$ has a local maximum at $x = 0$.

Let  $g(x) =|f'(x)|e^{f(x)}$ have a maximum value of $4\sqrt{e}$. If $g(x) = 4\sqrt{e}$ has rational solutions then:

a) $\int_{-1}^0g(x)dx=e-\frac{1}{e^{7}}$

b) The value of the sgn$(f(0))=-1$      (where sgn is the sign function)

c) $g(x)$ is not differentiable at one value of $x$

d) The value of $g\left(\tan{\frac{\pi}{4}}\right)=\frac{2}{e^7}$

(Since, I don't yet know how to write integrals on this website)
[The entire question is as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUdbW.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Math SE.  Please learn to use MathJax to typeset your mathematics since images are highly discouraged for multiple reasons. I already see here that $g(x)$ includes $f(x)$ in your written description but includes $f'(x)$ in the image.  I've edited your question to illustrate the use of typesetting.  Additionally , you will get a far better response if you are able to explain what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)'s a guide so you can learn how to write integrals.

Comment: Then what? Also, write your own attempt.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: $f(x)=a-bx^2$ for some $a,\,b\in\Bbb Q$ with $b>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = b-ax^2$ ($a$ is positive btw)

$g(x)=|-2ax|e^{b-ax^2}$ = $|2ax|e^{b-ax^2}$

Let $g(m) = 4\sqrt{e}$

$g(m)=|2am|e^{b-am^2}=4\sqrt{e}$

$2a|m|=4$

$a|m|=2$

$a^2m^2=4$

If $g(m) = 4\sqrt{e}$ where $4\sqrt{e}$ is the maximum of $g(x)$

Then $g'(m)=0$

$$g'(x)=\frac{2ax(1-2ax^2)e^{b-ax^2}}{|x|}$$

$$\frac{2am(1-2am^2)e^{b-am^2}}{|m|}=0$$
$$2am(1-2am^2)e^{b-am^2}=0$$
$$1-2am^2=0$$ (We know that $m$ is not equal to 0 so this is legal)
$$1=2am^2$$
$$am^2=\frac{1}{2}$$

Looking back at $a^2m^2=4$,
$$\frac{a}{2}=4$$
$$a=8$$
Thus $m=\pm\frac{1}{4}$

$b-am^2=\frac{1}{2} \space\space\space\space (e^{b-ax^2}=\sqrt{e})$

$b-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$

$b=1$

$f(x)=1-8x^2$

$g(x)=16|x|e^{1-8x^2}$
$$\int_{-1}^0g(x)dx =\int_{-1}^016|x|e^{1-8x^2}dx $$

Since we are integrating from negative values of $x$, $ |x| = -x$

$$\int_{-1}^0-16xe^{1-8x^2}dx $$
$$\int_{-7}^1e^udu $$
$$=e-\frac{1}{e^7}$$

Hence a is the correct option.